# Aquiring a file list from a shared sub folder using the Google API list

Tags: google-drive-api

Before writing java code I am trying to understand how the GoogleAPI works.
I am trying to get a list of files from a subdirectory of a shared drive,
If I use the file id from the high level shared folder I can get a list of all the files including subfolders.
Every time I try to get ONLY the files in a subfolder I get

```
{
 "domain": "global",
 "reason": "notFound",
 "message": "Shared drive not found: 1S_4HV0vi3zPr-gt2lRTCp5hAJFooElCn",
 "locationType": "parameter",
 "location": "driveId"  
}
```

I am using the website https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list
with the following parameters

```
Corpra = drive
deriveid
includeItemsFromAllDrives=true
pagesize=250
SupportsAllDrive=true
```

This is the partial output of the high level shared drive that I get the subfolder ID from

```
{
 "kind": "drive#file",
 "id": "1S_4HV0vi3zPr-gt2lRTCp5hAJFooElCn",
 "name": "2021",
 "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.folder",
 "teamDriveId": "0ACNyBdDB5wLXUk9PVA",
 "driveId": "0ACNyBdDB5wLXUk9PVA"
},
```

What am I doing wrong ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use the shared drive sub-directory folder id in [Files.list()](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list).
This method requires a `driveId` which is the ID of the shared drive to search.

You can use [Drives.list()](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/drives/list) to get a list of valid user shared drive

If you want to list the files inside the sub-directory folder, you need to add a query parameter that will indicate the file's parent folder id. See [Search for files and folders](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/search-files)

**Note:**

Some [File Resource](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files#resource) fields are not shown in the response body by default, if you want to show all fields, set `fields` parameter in [Files.list()](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list) to `*`

---

**For example:**

My shared drive sub-folder id: '1V2bi9xN8aWDWzCvMWC4oCqmOGHh1xxxx'

[image]

If I want to list all files under this sub-folder, I need to include this query parameter: `'1V2bi9xN8aWDWzCvMWC4oCqmOGHh1xxxx' in parents`

---

**Your request parameters will be:**

```
Corpra = drive
deriveid
includeItemsFromAllDrives=true
pagesize=250
SupportsAllDrive=true
q = 'shared drive sub-folder id' in parents
```

---

**Sample Response:**

```
{
 "kind": "drive#fileList",
 "incompleteSearch": false,
 "files": [
  {
   "kind": "drive#file",
   "id": "1_XlY8tgcJgj13FItftGrF77ixxxxx",
   "name": "subfolder_doc",
   "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.document",
   "teamDriveId": "0AJWF4SKro9kyxxxx",
   "driveId": "0AJWF4SKro9kyUxxxx"
  }
 ]
}
```

---

**(Update)**

Here is a sample request in java using [Drive.Files.List() methods](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/drive/v3/java/latest/com/google/api/services/drive/Drive.Files.List.html)

```
FileList result = service.files().list()
                .setCorpora('drive')
                .setDriveId('0ACNyBdDB5wLXUk9xxxx')
                .setPageSize(250)
                .setIncludeItemsFromAllDrives(true)
                .setSupportsAllDrives(true)
                .setQ("'1-mZjjMTrcmlNm6SnJQeSQxGxxxxx' in parents") 
                .execute();
```

Comment: Thank you for helping I understand your answer and now I am trying to implement it using the Drive() API as you stated.  I am getting compile errors  error: package drive does not exist
        FileList result = drive.files.list()
At the top of the java file I have the following imports

Comment: import com.google.api.services.drive.Drive;
import com.google.api.services.drive.DriveScopes;
import com.google.api.services.drive.model.File;
import com.google.api.services.drive.model.FileList;      Im kind of new to the Google API world so please forgive me if its something stupidly simple

Comment: Please refer to [Drive API Java Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/java) to learn more on how to use and setup drive API. Sample code was also provided in the reference document.

Comment: Thank  you I actually looked at that and thought it was for File() not Drive() that's why  I tried FileList result = Drive.files().list()  I Tried ```FileList result = service.files().list(
                    Corpra = drive,
                    driveid ="0ACNyBdDB5wLXUk9PVA",
                includeItemsFromAllDrives=true,
                pagesize=250,
                SupportsAllDrive=true,
                q = "'1-mZjjMTrcmlNm6SnJQeSQxGtJ7A1-T1J' in parents"
                )```
but none of the parameters are recognized,  I have tried service.Drive.list, as well as drive.list

Comment: Hi @MichaelLachina [service.files().list()](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/drive/v3/java/latest/com/google/api/services/drive/Drive.Files.html#list--) doesn't expect a string arguments. I updated the answer with a sample request in java using [com.google.api.services.drive package](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/drive/v3/java/latest/com/google/api/services/drive/package-summary.html)

Comment: By the way, please refrain from providing your personal private information such as unredacted driveId and subfolder id. (you can change some trailing characters when you provide some sample code snippet)

Comment: Thank  you so much, I have learned Quite a lot from you.  I just had to update the version of package and it all works now.  BTW  I did vote up your answer but because this was my first post it does not seem to count.